# Whats the easiest way to accept credit cards in an Android app?

Tags: android, payment

I'm looking for the most expeditious and easiest way to accept credit cards in my Android app. I have tried Braintree and am still tinkering with it. Also I looked into Paypal and it seemed the only easy way to do was to only allow payments actually with a Paypal account. Does anyone know any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There are many apis to do this but you can refer to these-

First one is in-app billing.
**In-app Billing**

In-app Billing is a Google Play service that lets you sell digital content from inside your applications
[link-](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html)

other apis-[link-](https://www.innerfence.com/apps/credit-card-terminal/developer-api)
They provide apis for iphone,android etc.